# Multiple between criteria on column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a very simple table containing 3 columns:

```
ID  |  Orders | Code
--------------------
  1 |      11 |  'OK'
  2 |      25 | 'ER1'
  3 |       0 |  'OK'
  4 |      30 | 'ER2'
  5 |      42 |  'OK'
```

I'm trying to create stored procedure to select rows that meet my criterias:

What I need is to be able to select rows that for example have less than 10 orders or more that 30.

so sample call to my procedure would be:

```
EXEC REPORT1 @code='OK', @orders0_10=1,@ordersMore30=1
```

This should return rows 3 and 5. Below is my procedure so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[REPORT1]
(
@code NVARCHAR (5) = '',
@orders0_10 INT = 0,
@orders11_20 INT = 0,
@orders21_30 INT = 0,
@ordersMore30 INT = 0,
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT TOP 1000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RPT.Nr) AS Lp,
    RPT.ID,
    RPT.Orders,
    RPT.Code
FROM MyData RPT (NOLOCK)
WHERE (@code = '' OR RPT.Code= @code)
AND
--(
   (@orders0_10 = 1 AND RPT.Orders<= 10)
--OR (@orders11_20 = 1 AND (RPT.Orders > 10 AND RPT.Orders <= 20))
--OR (@orders21_30 = 1 AND (RPT.Orders > 20 AND RPT.Orders <= 30))
--OR (@ordersMore30 = 1 AND RPT.Orders > 30)
--)
ORDER BY RPT.Nr
GO
```

**EDIT**
I'll try to clarify what I need.
If I specify criterias like here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25045/19 I'm getting 2 rows (1,3) and that is correct.

If I change them to this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25045/21 I also bet 2 rows (2,4) and that is correct.

But if I specify them as so: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25045/22 I should get union of previous results (1,2,3,4):

rows with Sales< 10 OR 20

**EDIT**
I got final working version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25045/33, hope this will be useful for someone.

Comment: didnt quite understood what you mean

Comment: I would like to apply multiple criterias based on procedure params, so if I specify `@orders0_10=1` I want only rows with Orders<10 (this part works), but if I specify `@orders0_10=1,@ordersMore30=1` I want rows that have Orders<10 OR Orders>30

Comment: Your first query with commented OR works well in your case. Why did you change OR to AND in your update?

Comment: Ok you have answer now from @TimSchmelter. I would have also suggested same.

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria are:

```
where (@orders0_10 = 0 OR RPT.Orders<= 10) AND
      (@orders11_20 = 1 OR (RPT.Orders > 10 AND RPT.Orders <= 20)) AND
      (@orders21_30 = 1 OR (RPT.Orders > 20 AND RPT.Orders <= 30)) AND
      (@ordersMore30 = 1 OR RPT.Orders > 30)
```

I think the problem is the `0` in the first row; it should be a `1`:

```
where (@orders0_10 = 1 OR RPT.Orders<= 10) AND
      (@orders11_20 = 1 OR (RPT.Orders > 10 AND RPT.Orders <= 20)) AND
      (@orders21_30 = 1 OR (RPT.Orders > 20 AND RPT.Orders <= 30)) AND
      (@ordersMore30 = 1 OR RPT.Orders > 30)
```

Comment: Got it! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25045/33 Thanks for help, I just needed to change only a little to get this working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COALESCE` "trick":

```
SELECT 
    RPT.ID,
    RPT.Orders,
    RPT.Code
FROM MyData RPT 
WHERE COALESCE(@code, RPT.Code) = RPT.Code
AND   COALESCE(@orders0_10, RPT.Orders)   <= RPT.Orders
AND   COALESCE(@ordersMore30, RPT.Orders) >= RPT.Orders
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abcec/9/0)

Comment: thanks for help, but unfortunately this isn't the result I would like to get. I've edited my question and added some samples of what data I should get.